# Toggling tr display in a table

Tags: javascript, html-table

Let's say this is my table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>three</td>
    <td>four</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>five</td>
    <td>six</td>
<table>
```

Using Javascript, I want to be able to toggle the `display: none` element of the rows below the one I click on... but only if I click inside the first cell in each row.

For example, if I clicked on the cell containing `a`, the `tr` containing the cells `b`, `three`, and `four` and the `tr` containing the cells `c`, `five`, and `six` wouldn't display until I clicked it again. Clicking `one` or `two` would not do anything, though.

The table I am going to be using this code on is much larger, though.

Comment: I am looking for plain old Javascript, yes.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery, it's really easy:

```
$("table tr td:first-child").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().nextAll().toggle();
});
```

I'll update my answer with a plain JavaScript answer if i find one.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
jQuery('table').find('tr').find('td:first').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).parent().next().toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/